# Cholesky decomposition of tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, matrix-decomposition, kronecker-product, cholesky-decomposition

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb R^{m\times m}$ be symmetric, positive definite, matrices. Let $C = A\otimes B$ be their [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_linear_maps). I want to compute the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) of $C$. Suppose I have available the Cholesky decompositions of $A$ and $B$. Is there a way to exploit this information in computing the decomposition of $C$?

Comment: If $A=\alpha^T\alpha$ and $B=\beta^T\beta$, isn't $A\otimes B=((\alpha\otimes \beta)^T(\alpha\otimes \beta)$?

Comment: Yes, also found this: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/reports/kronthesisschaecke04.pdf. A lot of decompositions are preserved under tensor products.

Comment: @kimchilover If you post an answer (just that) I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Cholesky decomposition of a matrix $M$ is a factorization of form $M=LL^T$, where $L$ is lower triangular and $T$ denotes  transpose.

So given Cholesky decompositions $A=\alpha\alpha^T$ and $B=\beta\beta^T$ one can obtain the factorization $A\otimes B = (\alpha \otimes \beta)(\alpha^T\otimes\beta^T)$.  To see that this actually *is* a Cholesky decomposition one checks that $L=\alpha \otimes \beta$ is lower triangular.  Inspection of examples should make this clear, but the only  formal proof I can think of is notationally complex, involving expressions relating row numbers of $L$ to those of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with formulas like $k=mi+j$ and statements like $mi+j>mr+s$ implies at least one of  $i>r$ and $j>s$ holds.